# Can you retrieve multiple hyperlinks from one cell in excel spreedsheet using macros

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, hyperlink

I'm trying to retrieve display text and hyperlinks from excel spreadsheet containing 1000+ links.
I have a macro function as listed below. The problem is that some of the Cells in this excel document have multiple hyperlinks in one cell. The macro retrieves only the first hyperlink from such cells.
Is there a way to retrieve all hyperlinks from single cell?

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Function GetHyperAddy(Cell As Range) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetHyperAddy = Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GetHyperAddy = "None"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Sub DistillHyperlinks()
    Dim HyperAddy As String, cl As Range, wsTarget As Worksheet, clSource As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set clSource = Selection
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTarget = Sheets("Hyperlink List")
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wsTarget = Worksheets.Add
        With wsTarget
            .Name = "Hyperlink List"
            With .Range("A1")
                .Value = "Location"
                .ColumnWidth = 20
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
            With .Range("B1")
                .Value = "Displayed Text"
                .ColumnWidth = 25
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
            With .Range("C1")
                .Value = "Hyperlink Target"
                .ColumnWidth = 40
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End With
        Set wsTarget = Sheets("Hyperlink List")
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    For Each cl In clSource
        HyperAddy = GetHyperAddy(cl)
        If Not HyperAddy = "None" Then
            With wsTarget.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Offset(0, 0), _
                                       Address:="", _
                                       SubAddress:=(cl.Parent.Name) & "!" & (cl.Address)
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = cl.Text
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Offset(0, 2), Address:=HyperAddy
            End With
        End If
    Next cl
    wsTarget.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be very helpfull (for both the community and you as a programmer) if you would indent your code.

Comment: `Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(1)` - that would explain only the first hyperlink.

Comment: A cell can have only one hyperlink. If you meant that it contains more web addresses, please share how they are separated. For example, you can write one web address and press `Enter`. You have created a hyperlink. Then you can select the cell and click in the formula bar, press `End` and press `Alt+Enter` and enter another web address below. Even if you add another address above, the hyperlink will always point to the initial address. Actually, by adding another address, you have only changed the `TextToDisplay` parameter. You could share a screenshot of the multiple 'hyperlinks' in a cell.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You are right, one cell in excel has only one hyperlink. Looks like the original document was in Google Sheets where it allowed multiple hyperlinks in one cell. But when I download and open it in MS Excel, it's lost and only have one link in cell. Hmm... I'm in strange situation now.